# Create a object by onclick JS

Tags: javascript, object

Could someone say is there a method how to create an object by simple click on a button?

```js
function createNewObject() {
// Create here a class
}

// Result should be:
    let car1 = {
      name: "Tesla",
      price: "20$"
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="createNewObject()"></button>
```

Comment: where are the object values coming from?  are you passing them in ?

Comment: What have you tried and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I think you can do a `new myObject(...)` and add more functions with `prototype` in ES5 otherwise you have to use `class` a constructor and define it in ES6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class Car, try this:

```js
class Car {
  constructor(name, price){
    this.name = name,
    this.price = price
  }
}

function createNewObject() {
  let car1 = new Car('Tesla', 20);
  console.log(car1);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="createNewObject()">Generate</button>
```